# Fractions and percentages

Tags: fractions, percentages

I have a question for my sons homework that he and I are struggling to solve.

Janet spent 1/5 of her salary and an additional 146 on food every month.
She then spent 1/3 of her remaining money and an additional 28 on transport.
If she saved the remaining 1208, how much was her salary.

I tried solving this by going backwords:
Initial = x
1/5 + 146 for food = x/5 +146
Remaining = 4/5x - 146

1/3 remaining + $28 on transport = 1/3 + 28 (4/5x - 146)
= (4/15x - 48.6666 + 112/5x - 4088)
= 22.6666x - 4136.666 = 1208
= 22.6666x = 5344.6666
x = 235

Which is obviously wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is best to stick with fractions on these problems and not use decimals which are not exact. Your mistake is in your third line. The one third should be applied to the $\frac{4}{5}x-146$ and the $28$ added to that.

Answer (score 4):

If $x$ is the salary, and if we assume the salary is all of the money there is to spend, then the entire salary $x$ can be partitioned as

$$x = \underbrace{(\tfrac15 x + 146)}_{\textrm{food}} + \underbrace{\tfrac13(\overbrace{x - (\tfrac15 x + 146)}^{\textrm{remaining after food}}) + 28}_{\textrm{transport}} + \underbrace{1208}_{\textrm{saved}}$$

Simplifying:

$$x = \tfrac15 x + 146 + \tfrac13x - \tfrac13(\tfrac15 x + 146) + 28 + 1208$$
$$x = \tfrac15 x  + \tfrac13x - \tfrac1{15} x + 1382 - \tfrac{146}{3}$$
$$\tfrac{15}{15}x - \tfrac3{15}x - \tfrac5{15}x + \tfrac1{15}x = \tfrac{4146}{3} - \tfrac{146}{3}$$
$$\tfrac{8}{15}x = \tfrac{4000}{3}$$
$$x = \tfrac{15}{8}\cdot\tfrac{4000}{3} = \boxed{2500}$$
So the salary is $2500$.

Answer (score 2):

Set $S=\text{salary}$ and partition in into $F=\text{food}$, $T=\text{transports}$ and $R=\text{remaining}$.

You know that
$$
F=\frac{S}{5}+146, \quad R=1208,
$$
and
$$
T=\frac{1}{3}(S-F)+28.
$$
Hence
$$
T=\frac{1}{3}(S-\frac{S}{5}-146)+28=\frac{4}{15}S-\frac{32}{3}.
$$

Lastly, since $F+T+R=S$, then
$$
\left(\frac{S}{5}+146\right)+\left(\frac{4}{15}S-\frac{32}{3}\right)+1208=S.
$$
Therefore $S=2500$.

Answer (score 1):

> Initial = x 1/5 + 146 for food = x/5 +146 Remaining = 4/5x - 146

This is really confusing. You say "Initial", but then you give the amount spent of food, and then you say "Remaining" without any line break.

> 1/3 + 28 (4/5x - 146) = (4/15x - 48.6666 + 112/5x - 4088)

You wrote "1/3 + 28 (4/5x - 146)", but then you calculated "(1/3 + 28) (4/5x - 146)". Those are different things, and both wrong.

Something that may have helped you in this case is if you had kept the units. 1/3 is a unitless quantity, but 28 has the unit of dollars. You can't add 1/3 and \$28, because they don't have the same units. If you instead have (1/3y +\$28), then now you're multiplying two dollars amounts, which gives you square dollars, which doesn't make any sense. You can't multiply \$28 and \$146. It's one third of the remainder plus \$28, not \$28 of the remainder plus one third. "Of" means times. So "1/3 of her remaining money and an additional 28 on transport." means "1/3 * (4x/5-\$146) + \$28".

> I tried solving this by going backwords:

Except that you went through it forwards. If you were going backwards, you'd start at "1/3 of her remaining money and an additional 28 on transport". If x is the amount she stated with, and y is the amount she had after buying food, then y-y/3-28 = 1208. So 2y/3-28 = 1208, and 2y/3=1236, so y = 1872. You can then plug 1872 in to the first part to solve for x.

BTW, you can escape dollar signs by putting a backslash in front of them.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how old your son is or whether he's in a math course where they're starting to use variables like $x$. You can solve it without algebra by starting from the end and working backwards.

Janet saved the remaining 1208.
She spent $28$ on transportation before that, so she had $1208+28=1236$.
She spent $\frac13$ of the remaining money before that, so $1236$ is $\frac23$ of what she had, so she had $\frac32*1236=1854$.
She spent $146$ on food before that, so she had $1854+146=2000$.
Finally, she spent $\frac15$ of her salary before that, so $2000$ is $\frac45$ of her salary, so her salary is $\frac54*2000=2500$.

With problems like this, it's always a good idea to check your answer by plugging it into the original problem.

Let Janet's salary be $2500$, the result we calculated above.
Janet spent $\frac15$ of her salary ($\frac15$ of $2500$ is $500$) and an additional 146 on food every month. So she spent $500+146=646$ on food, leaving her with $2500-646=1854$.
She then spent $\frac13$ of her remaining money ($\frac13$ of $1854$ is $618$) and an additional 28 on transport. So she spent $618+28=646$ on transport, leaving her with $1854-646=1208$.
She saved the remaining $1208$.